# Reference to object in array in object in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

For our application we have one complex global data object. Lets call this object A. Object A has a strong, nonatomic array with objects of class B, lets call them B1, B2, B3, etc. Each of these B objects can have an array again, with objects of type C, say C1, C2, etc...

Now when we create this complex structure at the first startup of the application, The C objects asynchronously starts downloading images etc. When this process is done, it calls a delegate function. This "finish loading event" clearly launches after the delegate has been set! The object is accessed through the singleton pattern.

However, when it finishes, the delegate in the C objects are nil.

We figured it had to do with referring to the object. The moment we set the delegate, we simply set the C object delegate by

```
[[A objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y].delegate = self;
```

However, when the loading of C finishes, and we check what the delegate is, it is nil. ObjectAtIndex is a read only method. Object C might contain an array itself as well, making the tree even deeper.

How to tackle this problem? Can we get a "reference" to the object in the array instead of an "copy"?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The above information is arbitrary and not actual code. It is just to give an impression of what is happening.

The problem is that there is supposed to be one object in a complex tree, however when i adjust this object and a little while later check it again, the adjustment was not applied.

Delegate declaration:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) id<HKWidgetModel> delegate;
```

Comment: create a small demo to verify the issue, show that code, explain what `self` is in this context...

Comment: He tells that self contains the complet multi dimensionnal array.

Comment: Self was just arbitrary, could be any class that contains the delegate method. 

Thanks for adjusting the code to snippet.

Comment: If your delegate property is declared weak and the delegate object has no strong reference elsewhere (at the time your async process finishes), it could cause the symptoms you're reporting.

Comment: I suggest logging the values of `[[A objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y]` as you assign their delegates and then log the value of `self` in `C` at the point where it tries to use the delegate.  Verify that the object address in the second log is matched by one in the first log.

Comment: Are you calling the delegate method from a block which was created before the delegate was set?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should use **Block** instead of delegate to avoid this complicity.

Comment: Can you give at least an exemple.

Comment: I want to know,For which purpose you are currently use delegate?